# How to run webpack + ReactJS without node.js on client-side?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Is it possible to run the webpack transpiler without client-side without  Node.js server?

My application is available to deploy SPA and use React 15.1.0 integrated with Babel-core 5.8.23. However, our server-side solution is proprietary and has no ability to change support for updates, being the same company in very complex services and applications, where have a Node.js service is available for only it.

Exist any way to run the React developed only on the front-end with code running in client-side.

**OBS:** my current main obstacle is being a modularized import of components that has the error .. `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Test Codes:

**index.html** and **main.js**

```js
// File "main.js"

import App from './components/App.js';

ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Aprendendo React</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Testes com código ReactJS">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel" src="main.js" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="app"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render: function() {
        return <h1>React Ok</h1>;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot run webpack on the client side.

but you can use **script** tags if your code can run on the browser(make sure you only use ES features that have browser support)

```
<script src="/components/App.js"></script>
```